# JNA long returned value different in 32 bit and 64 bit

Tags: java, jna

I am using JNA in my project to receive a long value from a C function in Windows.

The method is:

```
long identifier();
```

when I use my virtual machine (JRE 1.7.0_05 for windows 64) on 64 bits I use the compiled dll for 64 bits and I get this number:

```
identifier = 528913750
```

if I use a virtual machine (JRE 1.7.0_07 for windows 32) with the compiled dll for 32 bits, I get this number:

```
identifier = 369896101206
```

The right one is the first! (for 64 bits)

The binary value of them is:

```
64 bits =           11111100001101001010101010110
32 bits = 101011000011111100001101001010101010110
```

Somebody knows why I get this 1010110 at the beginning for 32 bits?

Comment: Sorry I solved by changing long to NativeLong from JNA

Comment: There is no code for identifier(), it was the native function implemented in c

Comment: I suggest you add this as answer and accept it. Watch your rate.

Answer (score 0):

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access#Mapping_types) there is a table describing the mapping for native types in JNA. The direct conversion to long is supported only for 64 bits, otherwise [NativeLong](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLong.html) must be used.

In this [article](http://www.360doc.com/content/10/0405/14/1140236_21681987.shtml) is also described how to map a native long.